# How to solve the problem with 'map' function on React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm doing project on React.js. I'm mapping the array and the error saying that the array is undefine even if it exists

```
    <ul>
      {details.extendedIngredients.map(ingredient => (
        <li id={ingredient.id}>{ingredient.original}</li>
      ))}
    </ul>
```

Full code:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

function Recipe() {
  let params = useParams();
  const [details, setDetails] = useState({});
  const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState("instructions");

 const fetchDetails = async () => {
    const data = await fetch(
      `https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/${params.name}/information?apiKey=${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}`
);
const detailData = await data.json();
setDetails(detailData);
};

useEffect(() => {
fetchDetails();
}, [params.name]);
console.log(details.extendedIngredients);

return (
  <DetailWrapper>
    <div>
      <h2>{details.title}</h2>
      <img src={details.image} alt="" />
   </div>
  <Info>
    <Button
      className={activeTab === "instructions" ? "active" : ""}
      onClick={() => setActiveTab("instructions")}
    >
      Instructions
    </Button>
    <Button
      className={activeTab === "ingredients" ? "active" : ""}
      onClick={() => setActiveTab("ingredients")}
    >
      Ingredients
    </Button>
    <div>
      <h3 dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: details.summary }}></h3>
      <h3 dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: details.instructions }}></h3>
    </div>
    <ul>
      {details.extendedIngredients.map(ingredient => (
        <li id={ingredient.id}>{ingredient.original}</li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  </Info>
</DetailWrapper>
 )}

 export default Recipe;
```

Comment: `const [details, setDetails] = useState({});` — It definitely doesn't exist initially. There's no `extendedIngredients` property in that object.

Comment: The component renders once before the data is loaded. You need to either use an appropriate object as initial state so that `details.extendedIngredients` is always an array or render the ingredients conditionally.

Comment: Also, .map() failing in React is asked almost on a daily basis now, please search before posting.

Answer (score 0):

As `setDetails`  supposed to save the details received from your API in an array, I guess that it must be initialised as an empty array

`const [details, setDetails] = useState({});`

As it will be an empty array, there will be no render when the component will be mounted from react.

Should be:
`const [details, setDetails] = useState({});`

Answer (score 0):

edit this three parts:

**first Part:**

```
useEffect(() => {
fetchDetails().then(res=>
  {setDetails(res.data); console.log(res)}
);
}, []);
```

**second Part:**

```
<ul>
  {details?.extendedIngredients?.map(ingredient => (
    <li id={ingredient.id}>{ingredient.original}</li>
  ))}
</ul>
```

**third Part:**

```
 const fetchDetails = async (params) => {
    const data = await fetch(
      `https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/${params.name}/information? 
     apiKey=${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}`

      return data;
  );
```

Comment: tell me what happen after this update, and i hope to push your code on github to correct your errors